# USB Wifi will not connect on Windows 7 (Even though the driver installs OK)

Tags: windows-7, usb, wireless-networking, network-adapter

Windows 7 will not connect to a WiFi network using a USB Network Adapter.

I have 3 adapters: a **Senoa SUB 364 (EXT)**, a **Repeatit SU2410 USB V2** and a **ZYXEL G202**. All of these devices install okay on Windows 7 Home Premium on my destop PC (64-bit) and on my Asus Wii Netbook (32-bit).

In each case the adapter can be enabled/disabled and the driver properties says it is working correctly. When I try and connect to a network Windows 7 behaves as though the adapter does not exist and reports no networks.

The Wii has an integrated adapter which works perfectly under Windows and connects to either of the 3 networks available to me.

I have done all the checks I can on the configuration. What seems odd to me is that it happens to all 3 devices on 2 different Windows 7 PCs both of which are working perfectly in any other respect.

This suggests the common denominator is me and I must be doing something wrong. What's also strange is that I cannot find any similar problems being reported on any of the forums.

From what reading I've been able to do it seems like the new WiFi virtualisation thingy in Windows 7 is not recognising the adapters which suggests I'm missing a configuration option somewhere.

Looking forward to finding out if I'm not alone or just being stupid.

Answer (score -1):

I've exactly the same problem. Tried three USB network adapters: Netgear WN111v2, D-Link DWA-140, and the Belkin USB 4000 series without success.

Comment: I solved my problem eventually. Not one simple solution but all described in:

http://forums.techguy.org/networking/890093-solved-usb-wifi-adapters-installed.html 

Pete Roberts